# is there a way in Imacros where I can execute a block of code for a certain time?

Tags: javascript, imacros

For example lets say  I want to run a block of code for 5 mins I want it to loop for 5 mins then stop.

This is how I have made a loop, is it possible to do anything to it which then halts loop after 5mins?

sorry if it is a stupid question but new to this

> for (;;) iimPlay("GHOST.iim");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming iimPlay is synchronous and that it takes less than 5 minutes to execute once:

```
var start = Date.now();
for (;;) {
  iimPlay("GHOST.iim");
  if(Date.now()-start > 300000) break;
}
```

Here we're checking the amount of milliseconds it's been since we started running the loop. As soon as it's been more than 300000 milliseconds (5 minutes) we break the loop.

if you want it to run for 5 minutes, wait 5 minutes, run again for 5 minutes forever you can do that with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

```
function runForFiveMinutesForever() {
    var start = Date.now();
    for (;;) {
      iimPlay("GHOST.iim");
      if(Date.now()-start > 300000) break;
    }
    setTimeout(runForFiveMinutesForever, 300000);
}
```

and run it with a call to runForFiveMinutesForever:

```
runForFiveMinutesForever();
```

Comment: Thank you Macmee, I forgot to mention that once the block of code has  executed for 5 mins I would like it to stop for 5 mins and play again.